# Проблема при вводе ip из textbox

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winsock

При попытке вывести ip, вместо заданного выводятся непонятные цифры.

```
char* ipvar;
ipvar =  (char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(ip->Text);
client(ipvar);

void client(char* ipvar){
    int error(0);
    WSADATA ws;

    WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2,2), &ws);

    SOCKET s = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(21);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipvar);
    messageLB->Items->Add(addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    connect( s, ( struct sockaddr* )&addr, sizeof(addr));
}
```

Ввожу в ip например - 1, выводится - 16777216

Comment: Никогда в жизни не работал с этим, но интуиция подсказывает что здесь что-то не так: `(char*)(void*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(ip->Text);`

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) утверждает что надо делать так: 
`(char*)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(managedString).ToPointer();`

Comment: Не помогло ....

Comment: все там понятно еслив ы хотите IP то вот  string ipaddr = inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&ip.daddr); в вашей записи он уже упакован в сетевой порядок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

когда вы передаете свой Ip в `addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipvar);` то **inet_addr** - упаковывет его в сетевой [порядок](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx) . Если вы хотите увидет его в том виде в ктором передовали то нужно вызывать вот так `inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&ip.saddr);` где `ip` это `struct iphdr`.